# bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, code-signing

So I have a project that I have been working on in swift. When I run it on the simulator everything works perfectly. When I try to build and run on my phone I get this error

I have deleted derived data.
Cleaned build with cmd+shift+alt+k
Deleted from my phone and tried to reinstall everything
Nothing wokrs

> bin/sh failed with exit code 1

I have attached a screenshot of what xcode says

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like a cocoa pods error.  You might want to check your pod file and/or uninstall, then reinstall the pods.

Comment: @OwenHartnett Im not sure no matter what pod I install or uninstall it just moves up to the next pod